# In VS2013 with TFS, a newly added file appears as Checked-In and does not appear in the Pending Changes list

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I have noticed this on several occasions, and have not yet found a suitable explanation or resolution to the issue. I am looking for a cause and solution.

We are using:

- VS2013 Pro Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
- Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013
- Microsoft Git Provider

On occasion, I will add a file to a branch in the solution. I can then observe the following:

- The file will briefly appear with the New File glyph (the plus sign), and then immediately change to the Checked In glyph (the lock icon).
- In the Changes tab in Team Explorer, the file does not appear in the Included Changes, Excluded Changes, or Untracked changes sections.
- **`git status` reports that the file is not displayed as a pending change, nor is it displayed as an untracked file.**
- If I view the branch in the repository, the file is not, in fact, checked in.
- The file does exist in the folder within the solution's path.

Note that the file did not previously exist in the repository. (This branch and repository are only a few weeks old, and this is easily verified.)

Comment: Is the file matched by `.gitignore`?